# How a reader account in Snowflake is different from a user with read only access in main account? what's the purpose of reader account?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The reader account can be used to share the data with users, where they can only run SELECT queries. How is it different than a user who is having a role with read-only access? What purpose does a reader account serve with a reader account?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, the Reader account purpose is to provide read-only data using shares to consumers, hence it is named reader account.

Reader account is not restricted by the conventional RBAC read-only privileges. You may create new users and grant any priviligies but the data that is being shared by the provider would be only read-only.

Reader account is one of the use cases for the Secure Data Sharing feature.

Details for all use cases: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-providers.html

Reader accounts enable providers to share data with consumers who are not already Snowflake customers, without requiring the consumers to become Snowflake customers.

**A reader account enables data consumers to access and query data shared by the provider of the account, with no setup or usage costs for the consumer, and no requirements for the consumer to sign a licensing agreement with Snowflake.**

The reader account is created, owned, and managed by the provider account, which assumes all responsibility for credit charges incurred by users in the reader account. Similar to standard consumer accounts, the provider account uses shares to share databases with reader accounts; however, a reader account can only consume data from the provider account.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html

Answer (score 1):

Reader account is for users/consumers who are not on Snowflake. Reader account helps to keep the workload and management separate from your main account.

If you are a data provider, and you would like to share the data with one of your colleagues, for example, you would create a user for them in your main account. However, if you are a data provider, and would like to share the data with users outside your organization, that are not currently signed up for Snowflake, you will create a reader account for them, and share the data with that reader account.

In the latter case, the data consumers can then further manage the user management in the reader account, without you, as a data provider, having to do so.

Reader accounts are very handy in testing scenarios, where you would like to keep the testing completely separate from your actual (main) account, or, when you want to share data with consumers who do not want to sign up for Snowflake and handle billing.